# Which modules can be disabled in apache2.4 on windows

Tags: security, apache-2.2, php, web-server

I have an Apache 2.4 webserver running on Windows. I am looking into system hardening and the config file `httpd.conf`. There are numerous load modules and I am wondering which modules I can safely disable for performance and / or security improvements.

Some examples of things I would think I can disable are:

```
LoadModule cgi_module
others like 
LoadModule rewrite_module
LoadModule version_module
LoadModule proxy_module
LoadModule setenvif_module
```

I am not so sure they can be disabled.

I am running php5 as a scripting engine, with no databases, and that is it. 
My loaded modules are:

> core mod_win32 mpm_winnt http_core mod_so mod_access_compat mod_actions mod_alias mod_allowmethods mod_asis mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_dav_lock mod_dir mod_env mod_headers mod_include mod_info mod_isapi mod_log_config mod_cache_disk mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_proxy mod_proxy_ajp mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_socache_shmcb mod_ssl mod_status mod_version mod_php5

Comment: Just go down the list.  You are the best judge to know if a module should be enabled or disabled.  We know nothing about your website implementation or what features it requires.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/  I wish there was greater detail in the descriptions.

Comment: You won't be able to disable the core modules.  Everything else can be disabled if you want it.  That is all the help I can provide.